# Is there a way to specify reference or value type arguments in javascript functions?

Tags: javascript

It would be cooler if you could

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Primitive datatypes are sent by value, objects and arrays are sent by reference.

Answer (score 2):

Related: [JavaScript: Passing by Value or by Reference](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/javascript_pass)